# jQuery Date() function returns December 31, 1969 instead of current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I'm learning jQuery from the Jon Duckett book "Javascript & jQuery: Interactive Front-End Development".  So far all the code I've copied from the book seems to be running smoothly, however this code has me stumped.  Basically what happens is when you click on a list item in the HTML it displays the date the click event occurred next to the li.  It works, but the date displays December 31, 1969 instead of the object clicked date.  I've been reading up on how to fix this, but I've had no luck.  Is there a different way to get this same result, or am I just missing something in the code?

The jQuery snippet and jsfiddle link are below:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sydneyellenh/qng9msL2/)

```
$(function(){
   $('li').on('click', function(e){
    $('li span').remove();
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(e.timeStamp);
    var clicked = date.toDateString();
    $(this).append('<span class="date">' + clicked + ' ' + e.type + '</span>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `e.timeStamp` returns `DOMHighResTimeStamp` and not `DOMTimeStamp`. Which is very less.  Due to which it sets the date as  default to 12/31/1969.

new Date(), creates a new date object with the current date and time. You don't need to setTime explicitly here:

```
var date = new Date();
var clicked = date.toDateString();
```

Comment: Ah, perfect!  I tried everything except for removing that line of code.  Thank you!

Comment: that's unlikely to be that - see the reference http://api.jquery.com/event.timeStamp/

jQuery event has the `timeStamp` property.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `date.setTime(e.timeStamp);` and things work properly:

```
$(function(){
    $('li').on('click', function(e){
        $('li span').remove();
        var date = new Date();
        var clicked = date.toDateString();
        $(this).append('<span class="date">' + clicked + ' ' + e.type + '</span>');
    });        
});
```